# Convert numeric entities to UTF-8

Tags: php

How can I replace all numeric entities with the appropriate UTF-8?

For example: in the source the string shows like this:

```
$string1 = "The Devil&#39;s in the Details";
$string2 = "D&#xF3;nde est&#xE1;s, hermano?";
```

And I need replace it with

```
echo string1; //OUTPUTS Should be: The Devil's in the details
echo string2; //OUTPUTS Should be: Dónde Estás, Hermano?
```

I tried [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) but it didn't work; any ideas?

Comment: What did `html_entity_decode` do?

Comment: Hello, first at all, what is the string source? if it is a document, probably you must try to convert the documents instead a php function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem with `html_entity_decode` was that it didn’t decode the `&#39;`, it’s because the default flags are set to decode everything *but* a single quote. Do not attempt to ask why this is; it is PHP.

Try `ENT_QUOTES`:

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5); # HTML5 is good
```

[That appears to work.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0PFz52)

Comment: +1, this is the correct solution, indeed. @josesanchez, you should accept the answer if it answers your question ;)